# Why's Windows keep losing my storage device on reboot?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, storage

I've got a machine running Windows 8.1 off a boot SSD, with the SATA spinning media attached via an Adaptec 6405e controller.  It works great coming up from a powered off state.  However, if a reboot is done from Windows, the storage controller disappears until another full shutdown/power up is done.  By disappears, I mean that the drive no longer shows up as mounted and the controller doesn't even show up in the hardware list.

Interestingly also, when a Windows 8.1 reboot is done, the BIOS self-test stuff doesn't run (so, presumably that's why the controller vanishes, the option ROM never gets called).  Is there some way to force Windows 8.1 to do a real reboot instead of a fast one?  Or, are there other options to make this work that I'm completely overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer ended up being to switch motherboard slots.  We thought (incorrectly on this board) that you could use a 1x slot for a 1x card.  Moving the controller card to the top x16 slot and the video card to the bottom x16 slot solved the problem.

Comment: Also seems to work fine when the HDC is in a 4x/16x slot too.  Just those pesky 1x slots that cause the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a "full" reboot in Windows 8 by using the "shutdown" batch command.

Follow these instructions to make the shortcut: http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/

But you'll want to change the command to do a reboot:

```
shutdown /r /t 0
```

Comment: This does not work.  It also does a fast reboot (no self-test run/no option ROMs loaded).

Comment: If that doesn't work, then it may be a problem with the mobo.  According to Microsoft Documentation, the shutdown command should bypass hybrid shutdown unless specifically called using the /hybrid switch.  Have you tried performing a reboot with a different OS, such as a Linux LiveCD?

Answer (score 0):

@nick I'm working with Brian on this and I tested your suggestion of using a LiveCD.  The first reboot I did worked OK, but subsequent reboots exhibit the same behavior as Windows.  I have open tickets with Adaptec and Gigabyte.  (Would have made this a comment, but was unable to)